# ERA-5 data downloader... other than CDS-API?

Tags: meteorology, models, reanalysis, era

The CDS API does not behave well on our machines.  Has anyone had any luck scripting their own ERA-5 reanalysis large-data download script?  Perhaps something that is not nearly as large, clunky, and annoying to use?

Thanks!

Comment: Good luck! I will be interested in the answer

Comment: @MatthewClarkson Not sure what the problem is. Have you tried it with OPeNDAP - https://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds630.0/ ?